# How to search using elastic search 8.8 java and get response without specifying target bean

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

In Elastic 6.8 spring data elastic I could query by providing an extractor;

```
ElasticSearchResultExtractor resultsExtractor;

elasticsearchOperations.query(searchQuery, resultsExtractor)

public class ElasticSearchResultExtractor implements ResultsExtractor<MyExtractorClass>
```

How can I do similar using `elasticsearch-java 8.8.0`?